# Capistrano: pty stuck

Tags: capistrano

When the code runs till the following lines:

```
INFO [68a97f97] Running /usr/bin/env sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/buyi/releases/20160105133812/public/assets/ as deployer@ec2-54-169-250-77.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
DEBUG [68a97f97] Command: /usr/bin/env sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/buyi/releases/20160105133812/public/assets/
DEBUG [68a97f97]    [sudo] password for deployer:
```

The screen was stuck and I am not able to enter password at all.

My settings in deploy.rb are the following:

```
set :pty, true
set :use_sudo, false
```

how can i fix it? please!

Answer (score 0):

Use `:use_sudo` option

```
set :use_sudo, false
```

Would work !!!

Comment: @oasisweng Let us know whether this option works for you or not ?